# Multiple Users base DN in Directory Services

Tags: 2013-sp1, ldap

Can we define multiple DN in "Users base DN" under Directory Services? Reason for this was  because of them has been defined in "Service Accounts" DN and some of them define under "Users" DN.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean setting in MMC than there can only be one entity. But the good thing is that this is used only for showing list of users when adding a new user, it doesn't affect users which are already in the tridion database, it also doesn't affect users which are added via group sync.